Quickly matching indices between a sorted list and a subset of that list
I have a large sorted list of 64 bit integers containing hundreds of millions of entries.
I also have a small sorted list that contains a thousand 64 bit integers, where every integer in the small list is in the large list.
I need to align these two lists, and find the indices of the matching elements in the large list.
large_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
small_list = [2, 6]
matching_indices = magic_function(large_list, small_list)
print(matching_indices) # Prints [1, 5], the indices in large_list

How can I do this most efficiently?
I have considered the following:

Using a merge join between the two lists. This unfortunately is O(max(n, m)), and takes too long due to the large lists being much larger than the small list.

Performing one binary search in the large list for every entry in the small list. This requires O(n log m) time, but is quite slow due to the poor cache locality when searching the large list.


Does anyone have any better suggestions?

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Have you actually profiled these approaches?

Can you have a separate dictionary / hash map that contains each value in the large list (the key) and its index (the value). Then you can iterate though your small list and check if it exists in your map and if it does you can get its index. This is an example of using extra space for a quicker lookup

Given m > n, You can do this in O( min(m, n log m) ) time.
You second approach is not too bad, and its deficiencies won't have anything to do with cache locality when you're coding in python.
It's going to be faster in practice, though, if you recursively split the larger list while iterating through the smaller list, like this:
def magic_function(big, small):
    output = []
    if len(big) < 1 or len(small) < 1:
        return output
    def doPart(bigstart, bigend, smallpos):
        while bigend > bigstart+1:
            bigmid = bigstart + (bigend-bigstart)//2
            if big[bigmid] >= small[smallpos]:
                # there may be matches in big and positions < bigmid
                smallpos = doPart(bigstart, bigmid, smallpos)
                if smallpos >= len(small):
                    return smallpos
            bigstart = bigmid
        # we are guaranteed bigend == bigstart+1 here
        # also guaranteed smallpos < len(small)
        if big[bigstart] == small[smallpos]:
            output.append(bigstart)
            return smallpos+1
        else:
            return smallpos
    doPart(0, len(big), 0)
    return output


For each item in the small list, iterate the large list until you find it, and start at the location after the one you found the previous item at. This means iterating each list a maximum of one time and keeps the access sequential.
You can't use any lookup faster than iterating the large list one time to build the lookup, then looking up into it one time for each item in the small list, so no lookup method can beat this even if the lookup is O(1) for all operations, and it doesn't use any extra space or cause any cache issues.
Another option would be to split the lists. If you use a binary search to find the middle item in the small list, you know all items in the lower half must occur before that point, and all items in the upper half must occur above, so there's no need to binary search the whole list. This reduces the number of steps (and memory you must load) for every item you find by remembering information from previous searches. You can probably retain even more information from past searches with some effort.
The other obvious choice is to parallelise.
That being said, if cache issues apply, you realistically just have to implement the options and then profile them to figure out which is faster in practice; no algorithm designer can know how your cache will perform in your situation.
